# Remove duplicate elements and it's child nodes from input xml

Tags: xslt, dataweave

I have the payload in xml  format from which we have to remove the duplicate parent node and the corresponding child node in dataweave or xslt.

```
<ns1:Hierarchy xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/Hierarchy" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/HierarchyResult" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <ns2:Parent>19543007</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13277558</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>13277558</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13599506</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>11465977</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>11580182</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13601740</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13709062</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13731947</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13735926</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14204010</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14209921</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>13601740</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13277558</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13599506</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>13735926</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13348972</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>13601740</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13277558</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13599506</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>11465977</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>11580182</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13601740</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13709062</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13731947</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13735926</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14204010</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14209921</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>11465977</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>11580182</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13601740</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13709062</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13731947</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13735926</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14204010</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14209921</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>11465977</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>11580182</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13601740</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13709062</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13731947</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13735926</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14204010</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14209921</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>11465977</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>11580182</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13601740</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13709062</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13731947</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13735926</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14204010</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14209921</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>11465977</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>11580182</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13601740</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13709062</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13731947</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13735926</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14204010</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14209921</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>11465977</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>11580182</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13601740</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13709062</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13731947</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13735926</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14204010</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14209921</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>99000016191</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>11465977</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
</ns1:Hierarchy>
```

**The desired output needs to be something like as below**

```
 <ns1:Hierarchy xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/Hierarchy" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/HierarchyResult" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <ns2:Parent>19543007</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13277558</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>13277558</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13599506</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>11465977</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>11580182</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13601740</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13709062</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13731947</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13735926</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14204010</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>14209921</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>13601740</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13277558</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13599506</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>13735926</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13348972</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
   <ns2:Parent>13601740</ns2:Parent>
   <ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13277558</ns2:Children>
      <ns2:Children>13599506</ns2:Children>
   </ns2:Children>
```

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated. I have tried various answers on dataweave and xslt but could filter out the duplicate items.

Answer (score 2):

The template matching `ns1:Hierarchy` should process child `ns2:Parent`
elements, limited to only the first element with particular content
(thus eliminating duplicate elements).

To do this, you need:

- Before the template: Create a `key` (I named it `parents`)
  matching `ns2:Parent` and saving its content (`use="."`).
- Within the template: Apply templates to `ns2:Parent` nodes, for which
  `generate-id ... [1]` predicate is true (details in the script).

The template matching `ns2:Parent` should:

- Copy its own element.
- Copy following sibling `ns2:Children` elements, but only these for
  which the first preceding sibling `ns2:Parent` is the current
  `ns2:Parent` element.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/Hierarchy"
  xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/HierarchyResult">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="parents" match="ns2:Parent" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:Hierarchy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ns2:Parent
        [generate-id()=generate-id(key('parents', .)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns2:Parent">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ns2:Children
      [generate-id(preceding-sibling::ns2:Parent[1])=generate-id(current())]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/ei5PwiW

Comment: Actually you do not need to re-generate second key at end. Simply index the first node: `<xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::ns2:Children[1]"/>`

Comment: Thank you so much for the inputs. Valdi.